# Generate random number & email activation

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm currently experimenting with php and have created a small HTML document uses a form to parse information such as email and name.

I've also created a separate php file which assigns parsed data (email, name), and saves this information into a database table as sign in information.

I've also created a random number that should generate every time the form has been filled in.

I then want to send an email to the user which will then be used to activate their accounts in the database. I am doing this by creating two extra fields in my db table, 1 to store the generation code and the other as a boolean value either 0 (false) or 1 (true).

I'm having difficulty with sending the email. The email itself is sending, but if you look at my $body variable on the code, i'm giving a link:

> http://localhost:8888/activation.php?acode=$acode

I'm trying to get the activation code to append after the .php and unsure why it is not?

I'll post my php code as it may be easier to scan through and have an idea of the process I have done:

```
$acode = rand(1111111111,9999999999); 

    $to = $email; 
    $subject = 'Please activate your account';
    $headers = 'From: welcome@oreon.com'; 
    $body = 'Hello ' . $first_name . ', \n\n Please click the link below to activate your account. \n\n http://localhost:8888/activation.php?acode=$acode \n\n Thanks.';

    // Create a new connection 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); 

    if($conn->connect_error) { 
        die ('Connection Failed'); 
    } else { 
        echo ('Connection Established <br>'); 

        if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'Oreon')) { 
            die('Database could not be reached'); 
        } else { 
            echo ('Database Reached'); 
        } // close brackets db selected 

        // Prepare SQL statements 
        $core_customer_insert = "INSERT INTO core_customer_information(firstname, lastname, email, password, activation_code, activated) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$user_password','$acode','0')"; 

        // Prepare SQL statements 
        $core_company_insert = "INSERT INTO core_company_information(name, reg_address, postcode, comp_reg_no, comp_utr_no, comp_vat_no) VALUES ('$company_name','$address_line','$postcode','$company_reg_no','$company_utr_no','$company_vat_no')";

        if($conn->query($core_customer_insert) === TRUE) { 
            echo ('Data successfully added'); 
            // Send activation email
            if(!mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) { 
                echo '<br>The activation email could not be sent at this time.'; 
            }
        } else { 
            die ('Data not added ' . $conn->error); 
        }

        if($conn->query($core_company_insert) === TRUE) { 
            echo ('Data successfully added'); 
            echo ('<br> ' . $activation_code_generator); 
        } else { 
            die ('Data not added ' . $conn->error); 
        }
    }
} // close brackets for connected
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: Use double quotes if you want to have variables parsed in strings. Or just concat them like you've been doing all this time.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_GET` or `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, just as the other said, you just have to contact them, but I'd like to help you a bit further.

Alright, so here's the issue with your code, think it about it like constructive criticism:

1. You are **not** protecting your queries, they are vulnerable to injections
2. There's a risk that two activation values might collide because you are just getting random values, not *uniquely* random values
3. You could avoid #2 but you'd have to make sure you **delete** the activation code once the account is activated
4. You are using procedural methods with a MySQLi object present
5. You are also not including e-mail data type headers

I have a few more concerns but considering that I was in the same position you are in a few years ago I won't touch on the aesthetics and all. I have decided to rewrite your code and comment it a little bit so that you can actually learn from it

```
<?php

# First we generate the randomly unique activation code, there is an incredibly small chance of collision but that would only happen once in millenia or if you don't delete any activation values for centuries

$acode = md5(uniqid());

# If you are doing this for organization, I recommend arrays

$mailData = array(
        "to"        =>  $email, # User's email
        "subject"   =>  "Please activate your account", # E-mail subject, should be same as body title
        "headers"   =>  "From:  <you@atemail.com>\r\n
                        To: ".$first_name." <".$email.">\r\n
                        MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
                        Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n", # From: <your or sender's email>, To: User's name <user's email>, MIME-Version: Mime version, don't worry too much about this one. COntent-type: Charset and type of content that the email will have
        "body"      => "<html>
                        <head>
                            <title>Please activate your account</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            Hello ".$first_name . ", \n\n Please click the link below to activate your account. \n\n http://localhost:8888/activation.php?acode=".$acode." \n\n Thanks.
                        </body>
                        </html>" # Actual content of the email
    );

// Create a new connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); 

if ( $conn->connect_error )
{
    # I'm assuming this is a testing environment so I'll keep my comments about the way you are reporting progress off
    die ('Connection Failed'); 
}
else
{
    echo ('Connection Established <br>'); 

    # No need for this, you are already checking for connection errors on the creaton of the MySQLi object

    /*
    if ( !mysqli_select_db($conn, 'Oreon') )
        die('Database could not be reached'); 
    else
        echo ('Database Reached');
    */

    // Prepare SQL statements
    # Please protect your queries

    $core_customer_insert = "INSERT INTO core_customer_information(firstname, lastname, email, password, activation_code, activated) VALUES (
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($first_name)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($last_name)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($email)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($user_password)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($acode)."',
    '0')"; 

    // Prepare SQL statements 
    $core_company_insert = "INSERT INTO core_company_information(name, reg_address, postcode, comp_reg_no, comp_utr_no, comp_vat_no) VALUES (
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($company_name)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($address_line)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($postcode)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($company_reg_no)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($company_utr_no)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($company_vat_no)."')";

    if ( $conn->query($core_customer_insert) === TRUE )
    { 
        echo ('Data successfully added'); 

        // Send activation email

        if( !mail($mailData['to'], $mailData['subject'], $mailData['body'], $mailData['headers']) )
            echo '<br>The activation email could not be sent at this time.'; 

    }
    else
        die ('Data not added ' . $conn->error);
}
```

Keep in mind that I didn't exactly tested but it should work fine. Make sure to read the code and go over the comments. Good luck.

Comment: One quick question, using the uniqid(), its creating and storing the value 0 each time. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird, is the activation code a VARCHAR? If it isn't the server will try to parse the integer value of the text, hence the reason it stores 0, change it to VARCHAR if it's an INT column

Comment: Yeh sorry, the type was int xD my apologies.